# Regex issue with comma

Tags: javascript, regex

On blur from a certain text field `#city` , I want to remove the error message that is shown.

It works with letters numbers and dots, but I can't get it to work with a comma to.

Code:

```
$('input#city').blur(function() {
        var cityc = $(this).val();
        if ( /^[a-z 0-9 \.']{2,25}$/i.test(cityc) ) {
            $(this).removeClass('invalid');
            $('span.cityerror').removeClass('active');
        }
    });
```

So, if the error message exists, and the text's value contains letters numbers or dots, on blur the error message disappears, but if there is a comma it doesn't.

I tried modifyng the line in question like so:

```
if ( /^[a-z 0-9 \. ,']{2,25}$/i.test(cityc) ) {
```

As you can see I added a comma in the expression, but it still won't disappear on blur if the input's value contains a comma. Why?

UPDATE:

So if I enter for example `city` on blur the message disappears, but `city,` or `city ,`, it does not.

Comment: Are you sure you want to allow spaces in `cityc`?

Comment: Yes. I just need the comma thing to work.

Comment: Can you post what you exactly entered into the textbox? Values that work and values (with comma) that don't? Also: why do you have spaces between your ranges (a-z 0-9)?

Comment: Just posted the values. As for spaces, no particular reason.

Comment: For me it does match: http://regex101.com/r/cS8uS0/2 There must be something else wrong. Are you sure cityc has the value 'city ,'?

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a deeper look now and let you know.

Comment: Figured it out, the form was loaded via ajax and I had to use `on` like on('blur','input#city',function(e) {

Answer (score 0):

I am not a regex expert but

You may try this:

```
if(/^([a-z0-9]+[.', ]?[a-z0-9]*)+$/i.test(cityc)) {
    ...
}
```

**EDITED**

```
what about this:
if(/^[A-Za-z0-9.', ]+$/.test(cityc)) { ... }
```

Comment: Your regex is prone to catastrophic backtracking. Paste this into your console: `/^([a-z0-9]+[.', ]?[a-z0-9]*)+$/i.test("fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff$")` and see your browser freezes up.

Comment: The author of the question already figured the problem out. It had nothing to do with the regex itself. See his/her comments. :-)